# A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored

Tags: spring-security, tomcat7, java-7

Spring Security basic example gives this exception.

Error: "A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored. Please check the ordering in your  namespace or FilterChainProxy bean configuration"

I have checked many posts on this same issue. But could not find any solution. Anyone able to deploy a hello spring security?

I am using these versions - Spring 3.2.0.RELEASE / Spring security 3.2.0.RELEASE / Tomcat 7 / Java 1.7.

Here is my code:

**web.xml**

```xml
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Spring security sample Web Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml,
            /WEB-INF/security-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**spring-context.xml**

```xml
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="jay" password="jay" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/hello.jsp" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </http>

</beans:beans>
```

**MyController.java**

```java
package com.jai.spring.security.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class MyConroller {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/security", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String security(Model model) {
            System.out.println("calling ... /security");
            model.addAttribute("name", "Jay");
            return "pages/hello";
        }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/profile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String profile(Model model) {
            System.out.println("calling ... /profile");
            return "user/profile";
        }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.jai.spring.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>springsec</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springsec Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring-version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring-version>
        <spring-security-version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring-security-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>springsec</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>

                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>localhost</server>
                    <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**File structure**

[image]

Comment: You've set a pattern to match any url, and then further down, you define a pattern for root, which has been overridden by the previous pattern. You can't have both!

Comment: Are you sure there are no other `<http>` security configurations in your Spring contexts? Never saw this error before, but it basically says that you have defined two security filter chains, where the first one will simply take all the traffic due to its matching pattern.

Comment: @Chris Thanks Chris. Do you mean inside web.xml ?  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> &  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> ? Should I change this ?

Comment: Just noticed your error... you are using the same context XML file for the root context and for the dispatcher context. That XML contains security config so you have a duplicate security definition. Even more... you are defining the same context twice for the root context.

Comment: @PavelHoral Many thanks for trying to help me. Yes for a trial & error I added <init-param><param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value></init-param>  inside dispatcher and I have removed it now. Should I correct any thing else more ?

Comment: @Jay I've answered in a proper answer. Hopefully that will shed some light on your trials.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are incorrectly using your XML context files, which lead to duplicate bean definition  (including security config). And `<http>` configuration without a `pattern` attribute maps to `/**` => your error.

---

Here you define root XML context file for the servlet:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Create a new context config instead (you can omit this declaration if you use the default name, which is `{your-servlet-name}-servlet.xml` => `spring-dispatcher-servlet-servlet.xml`):

```xml
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

---

The difference between the *root* and the *servlet* contexts was discussed several times here on StackOverflow. Basically the root context (`spring-context.xml` and `security-context.xml` in your case) should hold application wide beans (services, DAOs, including security configuration) and the dispatcher context (`dispatcher-servlet.xml` in my example) should hold dispatcher servlet specific beans like controllers, view resolvers, etc.

Further reading:

- [Why DispatcherServlet creates another application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833767/why-dispatcherservlet-creates-another-application-context)
- [Difference between applicationContext.xml and spring-servlet.xml in Spring Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-xml-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring)
- [Why use Spring ApplicationContext hierarchies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132604/why-use-spring-applicationcontext-hierarchies)

Comment: I've removed the first part of the answer. I thought there are two XML files with the same name, but one was *spring* and the other one was *security*. So the only error is in the servlet context location.

Comment: Many thanks you are a star. This solved my problem which I was breaking for 3 days. Thanks for the other links.