# Weblogic Spring Security "A universal match pattern ('/**') defined before other patterns"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, weblogic11g

Hi I'm trying to deploy my small spring webapp with spring security on weblogic 10.3.6 and I always getting this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored. Please check the ordering in your <security:http> namespace or FilterChainProxy bean configuration
```

I was read about duplicate root context and duplicate http which rewrite my secound context with default http, where first one is /** and overshadowing secound which will never be executed. 
How can I prevent this type of error and load context only once ?

**applicationContext.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!--bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" 
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" /> <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" 
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.url}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" 
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" / -->

    <!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc) -->


    <import resource="spring-security.xml" />

</beans>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<security:http auto-config="true">  
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.jsp" default-target-url="/hello.jsp" always-use-default-target="true" />
</security:http>

<security:http pattern="/login.jsp*" security="none"/>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="pawel" password="pawel1" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <security:user name="bob" password="bob1" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  version="2.5">


    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812698/a-universal-match-pattern-is-defined-before-other-patterns-in-the-filter

Comment: But you do have `/**` as the first pattern in your `<security:http>`. Is it there for a purpose? The error massage makes sense: other patterns will be ignored.

Comment: I was read that but i still don't know how to fix my configuration.

Comment: I removed  <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" /> and error is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move:

```
<security:http pattern="/login.jsp*" security="none"/>
```

above

```
<security:http auto-config="true">  
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.jsp" default-target-url="/hello.jsp" always-use-default-target="true" />
</security:http>
```