# Spring - register custom servlet with XML Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to add a custom servlet to my Spring Boot 1.5.8 app.
I have an Spring Security XML file where URLs to be authenticated are specified and it works fine.

So now I added the following config file

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new EventDispatcherServlet(), "/notification/event");
        return bean;
    }
}
```

When I run the app now I got the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored. Please check the ordering in your <security:http> namespace or FilterChainProxy bean configuration
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator.checkPathOrder(DefaultFilterChainValidator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator.validate(DefaultFilterChainValidator.java:55)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.afterPropertiesSet(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

I added the rule `"/notification/event"` to the security XML file but it made no difference.

The relevant part from the security XML:

```
<!-- ******************** rules with encryption and HMAC authentication ******************** -->
<security:http create-session="stateless" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" auto-config="true" 
            entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint" pattern="/**" >
    <!-- HMAC only -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/utils/logheaderpattern/check" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/executionflow/approve" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/executionflow/approve_and_forced_start" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/utils/maintenancewindow/next/**" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/utils/maintenancewindow/isin/**" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/executionflow/start/manual" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/executionflow/start/eventlife" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/executionflow/skip/eventlife" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/executionflow/start/scheduled" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/utils/cron/nextrun" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/utils/expression/check" access="authenticated" />
    <!-- HMAC and encryption (set in encryptionFilter) -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/worker/command/**" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/worker/event" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/worker/system/**" access="authenticated" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/notification/event/**" access="authenticated" />
    <!-- deny all others -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
    
    <security:csrf disabled="true" />
    
    <security:custom-filter ref="uniqueRequestFilter" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    <security:custom-filter ref="encryptionFilter" after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
    <security:custom-filter ref="hmacAuthenticationFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
</security:http>
```

I don't want to convert the security XML file to Java config as I said before it works fine and it would be a huge work and lots of testing.

So I presume I should register the custom servlet in XML...? However I am not sure if it makes any difference.

I'd appreciate any help, thank you very much!

Regards,
V.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue root cause likely related to this one: [A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812698/a-universal-match-pattern-is-defined-before-other-patterns-in-the-filter)

Since you added new servlet, did you add something to your spring root context or dispatcher context? Can you paste the content of the file as well.