# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to register servlet with name 'dispatcher'.Check if there is another servlet registered under the same name

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, illegalargumentexception, spring-java-config, servlet-mapping

**My initializer class**

```
public class HomeServlet extends 
AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {

    return null;
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {

    return new Class<?>[]{SpringContextConfig1.class};
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {

    return new String[] {"/home"};
}
```

}

**Configuration Class**

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"spittr.controllers"})
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringContextConfig1 extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver ivr=new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    ivr.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    ivr.setSuffix(".jsp");
    ivr.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
    return ivr;
}
```

}

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {


@RequestMapping(value="/home",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(){
    return "home";
}
```

}

This is a very simple program, I wrote to test the JavaConfig of Spring MVC.I exactly followed all the steps from "Spring in Action" book.

When I run this code, I'm getting this error

> 09:41:37,854 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./spittr: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./spittr: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to register servlet with name 'dispatcher'.Check if there is another servlet registered under the same name.
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to register servlet with name 'dispatcher'.Check if there is another servlet registered under the same name.
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:236)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
>       ... 6 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to register servlet with name 'dispatcher'.Check if there is another servlet registered under the same name.
>       at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.registerDispatcherServlet(AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.java:98)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.onStartup(AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.java:71)
>       at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:186)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:171)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:234)

**The hightlight of the error is that** " *Failed to register servlet with name 'dispatcher'.Check if there is another servlet registered under the same name. at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)* "

Please help me to solve this problem. I using WildFly-10 on eclipse.

Comment: Thank you for the edit BalusC

Answer (score 0):

1. use the configuration class as follows:

   ```
   @ComponentScan(basePackages={"spittr.controllers"})
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebMvc
   public class SpringContextConfig1 extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

       @Override            
       public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
           InternalResourceViewResolver ivr=new InternalResourceViewResolver();
           ivr.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
           ivr.setSuffix(".jsp");
           ivr.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
           registry.viewResolver(ivr);
       }
   }
   ```

   Basically you're extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` without inheriting any of its methods (in my 4.3.3 Spring version al least).
2. since you have a single `DispatcherServlet` here, you can add the `SpringContextConfig1` class to the root context and leave the servlet context empty: switch the body of the method `getServletConfigClasses()` under the `getRootConfigClasses()` and *vice versa* - see [A Bit on `ApplicationContext` Hierarchies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258758/getservletconfigclasses-vs-getrootconfigclasses-when-extending-abstractannot/35441381#35441381).

---

Moreover, the `DispatcherServlet` mapping is more likely `/` instead of `/home`:

```
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] {"/"};
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer. Unfortunately,  it's still throwing the same error.

Comment: i'll further investigate!

Comment: ah ok... `configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry)` it's not a f**** bean! The `@Bean` annotation should be removed

Answer (score 0):

My friend encountered the same problem. 
The problem was that the correct package name was not set for the class. 
AAAAnd clean the project before packaging!!!

Here is the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/starrykai/spittr)

Answer (score 0):

you can do a few things to overcome that issue.

1. delete the target directory, and re-deploy the web server.[the target directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CGrV.png)
2. If your project is a maven project, you can hit "maven clean package" within the pom.xml file and re-deploy the web server.[mvn clean package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdJob.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).