# Dispatcherservlet is not able to locate Config class when using java based configuration

Tags: java

My project structure is:-

Java Resources

```
src
    com.pizzeria.config
     AppConfig.java
     MySpringDispatcherServletInitializer.java
```

WebContent

```
META-INF
    MANIFEST.MF
WEB-INF
    lib
    view
        welcome.jsp
```

Contents of my AppConfig.java file

```
package com.pizzeria.config;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.pizzeria.*")
@PropertySource("classpath:*.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    // set up a logger for diagnostics

        private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    // define a bean for ViewResolver

        @Bean
        public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

            InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

            viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
            viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

            return viewResolver;
        }


         @Bean
           public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
             EntityManagerFactory emf){
               JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
               transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
               return transactionManager;
           }

        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localEntityManagerFactory() {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localEntityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            localEntityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
            localEntityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.pizzeria");
            localEntityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
            localEntityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
            return localEntityManagerFactory;
        }

        @Bean
        public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter() {
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
        }

        Properties additionalProperties() {
               Properties properties = new Properties();
               properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                                        env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
               properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", 
                                        env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
               properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", 
                                        env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"));
               properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", 
                                        env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache"));
               properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql",
                                        env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
               properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", 
                                        env.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));

               return properties;
           }

        @Bean
        public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

            dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driver"));
            dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
            dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
            dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
            return dataSource;
        }
}
```

Contents of my DispatcherServetInitializer

```
package com.pizzeria.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MySpringDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class [] {AppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String [] {"/"};
    }



}
```

The error which i'm getting while running my application on tomcat :-

```
19-Aug-2018 20:13:37.805 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 3 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
19-Aug-2018 20:13:37.936 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
19-Aug-2018 20:13:38.055 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:194)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:620)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:521)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5256)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
    ... 25 more

19-Aug-2018 20:13:38.078 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
19-Aug-2018 20:13:38.085 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1037)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1013)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:525)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4837)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5478)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How can I fix this error? I searched a lot about it but everywhere they are saying to use @EnableWebMvc on the configuration class. I already have it in my config class.But still don't know why container is looking for applicationContext.xml. 
Can anyone help me to get rid out of this error

I'm using spring-webmvc 5 version and i also deleted web.xml file from my tomcat

Answer (score 0):

The root configuration is required, the servlet configuration is optional.

*To fix:* Move `new Class [] {AppConfig.class}` to `getRootConfigClasses()`.

As **documented** in the javadoc of [`AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.html):

> Implementations are required to implement:
>
> - `getRootConfigClasses()` -- for "root" application context (non-web infrastructure) configuration.
> - `getServletConfigClasses()` -- for `DispatcherServlet` application context (Spring MVC infrastructure) configuration.
>
> If an application context hierarchy is not required, applications may **return all configuration via `getRootConfigClasses()` and return `null` from `getServletConfigClasses()`**.

See also StackOverflow question [getServletConfigClasses() vs getRootConfigClasses()` when extending AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35258758/5221149).

Comment: still there's same problem even after moving AppConfig.class to rootConfiguration . Don't know what's going wrong?

Comment: this is the error i'm getting after changing things:-
 20-Aug-2018 14:04:49.701 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!

Comment: That is a different error, so not "same problem". As your current issue has been fixed, and you're on to the next issue, create a new question showing your updated code and the new stacktrace.

Comment: yes friend i've updated the code and posted u can refer below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51942336/dispatcherservlet-is-not-able-to-locate-config-class

Comment: I thought you said you got a different error when you moved AppConfig.class to rootConfiguration.