# Dispatcherservlet is not able to locate Config class

Tags: java

New Project Structure :-

```
Java Resources
    src
        com.pizzeria.config
            AppConfig.java
            MySpringDispatcherServletInitializer.java
            SpringSecurityConfig.java
            SpringSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java

        com.pizzeria.controller
            LoginController.java
            DemoController.java

WebContent
        META-INF
            MANIFEST.MF
        WEB-INF
            lib
            view
                fancy-login.jsp
                index.jsp
                access-denied.jsp
```

AppConfig.java

```
package com.pizzeria.config;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.pizzeria.*")
@PropertySource("classpath:*.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

        private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    // define a bean for ViewResolver

        @Bean
        public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

            InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

            viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
            viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

            return viewResolver;
        }

         @Bean
           public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
             EntityManagerFactory emf){
               JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
               transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
               return transactionManager;
           }

        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localEntityManagerFactory() {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localEntityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            localEntityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
            localEntityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.pizzeria");
            localEntityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
            localEntityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
            return localEntityManagerFactory;
        }

        @Bean
        public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter() {
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
        }

        Properties additionalProperties() {
               Properties properties = new Properties();
               properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                                        env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
               properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", 
                                        env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
               properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", 
                                        env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"));
               properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", 
                                        env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache"));
               properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql",
                                        env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
               properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", 
                                        env.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));

               return properties;
           }

        @Bean
        public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driver"));
            dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
            dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
            dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
            return dataSource;
        }
}
```

MySpringDispatcherServletInitializer.java

```
package com.pizzeria.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MySpringDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class [] {AppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        /*return new Class [] {AppConfig.class};*/
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String [] {"/"};
    }



}
```

SpringSecurityConfig.java

```
package com.pizzeria.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.UserBuilder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        // add our users for in memory authentication

        UserBuilder users = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(users.username("john").password("test123").roles("EMPLOYEE"))
            .withUser(users.username("mary").password("test123").roles("EMPLOYEE", "MANAGER"))
            .withUser(users.username("susan").password("test123").roles("EMPLOYEE", "ADMIN"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
            .antMatchers("/leaders/**").hasRole("MANAGER")
            .antMatchers("/systems/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/showMyLoginPage")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");

    }

}
```

SpringSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java

```
package com.pizzeria.config;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SpringSecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

LoginController.java

```
package com.pizzeria.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/showMyLoginPage")
    public String showMyLoginPage() {

        // return "plain-login";

        return "fancy-login";

    }


}
```

DemoController.java

```
package com.pizzeria.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class DemoController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showHome() {

        return "index";
    }
}
```

Error Stacktrace :-

```
21-Aug-2018 11:12:10.492 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 3 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
21-Aug-2018 11:12:10.634 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
21-Aug-2018 11:12:10.768 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:194)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:620)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:521)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5256)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
    ... 25 more

21-Aug-2018 11:12:10.768 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5256)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

21-Aug-2018 11:12:10.793 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
21-Aug-2018 11:12:10.800 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
21-Aug-2018 11:12:10.803 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1037)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1013)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:525)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4837)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5478)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I also tried to register SpringSecurityConfig.class into getRootConfigClasses() along with AppConfig.class but it didn't worked

Comment: I think the message is clear: `FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`. Also it is not clear what you are asking

Comment: i'm saying i'm unable to run my app on tomcat spring context is not getting up

Comment: Please check your `JUnit tests` configuration

Comment: Why are you using legacy configuration for a new Spring application instead of using Spring Boot?