# Spring Security - No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to repeat from the Spring Security documentation and trying to protect one web page as a test. I do everything strictly according to the documentation as the spring writes.

[Spring Documentation - 1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication-jdbc)
[Spring Documentation - 2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer-with-spring-mvc)
[Spring Documentation - 3](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#mvc)

But it does not work. I have been tormented by this issue for 7 days. I'm going crazy.
I do not know what to do with this and how to overcome this mistake. It occurs at the assembly stage of the project.
Who can help please.

**Here is error log:**

```
C:\TomCat\apache-tomcat-9.0.30\bin\catalina.bat run
[2020-02-22 12:42:59,722] Artifact ConcretePage:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\ѓҐ­­ ¤Ё©\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_ConcretePage_2"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\TomCat\apache-tomcat-9.0.30"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\TomCat\apache-tomcat-9.0.30\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\TomCat\apache-tomcat-9.0.30\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\TomCat\apache-tomcat-9.0.30\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.416 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.30
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.418 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Dec 7 2019 16:42:04 UTC
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.418 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.30.0
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.419 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.419 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.419 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.419 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.419 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_241-b07
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.419 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.419 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Р“РµРЅРЅР°РґРёР№\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_ConcretePage_2
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.420 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\TomCat\apache-tomcat-9.0.30
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.420 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Р“РµРЅРЅР°РґРёР№\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_ConcretePage_2\conf\logging.properties
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.421 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.421 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.421 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.421 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.422 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:\Users\Р“РµРЅРЅР°РґРёР№\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_ConcretePage_2\jmxremote.password
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.422 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=C:\Users\Р“РµРЅРЅР°РґРёР№\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_ConcretePage_2\jmxremote.access
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.422 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.422 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.423 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.423 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.423 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Р“РµРЅРЅР°РґРёР№\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_ConcretePage_2
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.423 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\TomCat\apache-tomcat-9.0.30
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.424 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\TomCat\apache-tomcat-9.0.30\temp
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.424 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.23] using APR version [1.7.0].
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.424 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.424 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.432 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019]
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.878 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.928 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.934 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [840] milliseconds
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.984 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
22-Feb-2020 00:43:01.985 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
22-Feb-2020 00:43:02.003 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
22-Feb-2020 00:43:02.017 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
22-Feb-2020 00:43:02.022 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [86] milliseconds
Connected to server
[2020-02-22 12:43:02,357] Artifact ConcretePage:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
22-Feb-2020 00:43:06.552 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
22-Feb-2020 00:43:06.592 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
22-Feb-2020 00:43:07.807 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
22-Feb-2020 00:43:07.818 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4683)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5146)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1728)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:289)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:289)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
[2020-02-22 12:43:07,866] Artifact ConcretePage:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1695)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1253)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
        ... 62 more
22-Feb-2020 00:43:07.828 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
22-Feb-2020 00:43:07.834 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
22-Feb-2020 00:43:12.010 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory РЈСЃС‚Р°РЅРѕРІРєР° РІРµР± РїСЂРёР»РѕР¶РµРЅРёСЏ РІ РїР°РїРєСѓ [C:\TomCat\apache-tomcat-9.0.30\webapps\manager]
22-Feb-2020 00:43:12.209 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\TomCat\apache-tomcat-9.0.30\webapps\manager] has finished in [199] ms
```

**Below is my project**

**package** com.concretepage.**config**;

**FreeMarkerConfig.class**

```
    package com.concretepage.config;
```

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.concretepage"})
public class FreeMarkerConfig {

    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer() {
        FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        configurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/templates");
        configurer.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return configurer;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
        viewResolver.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        viewResolver.setCache(false);
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

**MessageWebApplicationInitializer.class**

```
    package com.concretepage.config;
```

```
import com.concretepage.security.WebSecurityConfig;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

@Order(1)
public class MessageWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{ WebSecurityConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{ SQLConfig.class, FreeMarkerConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

**SQLConfig.class**

```
    package com.concretepage.config;
```

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.concretepage.security")
public class SQLConfig {

    public SQLConfig() {
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysecurity?serverTimezone=UTC");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("root");
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("1234");
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }
}
```

**package** com.concretepage.**security**;

**SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.class**

```
    package com.concretepage.security;
```

```
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

@Order(2)
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

**WebSecurityConfig.class**

```
    package com.concretepage.security;
```

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.*;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

import javax.sql.DataSource;


@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // ensure the passwords are encoded properly
        User.UserBuilder user = User.builder();
        auth
                .jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .withDefaultSchema()
                .withUser(user.username("user").password("{noop}password").roles("USER"))
                .withUser(user.username("admin").password("{noop}password").roles("USER","ADMIN"));
    }
}
```

**package** com.**concretepage**;

**HomeController.class**

```
    package com.concretepage;
```

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home () {
        return "/home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login () {
        return "/login";
    }

}
```

**POM.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.concretepage</groupId>
    <artifactId>ConcretePage</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${encoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <dependencies>

<!--        Spring Security-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>



<!--        Spring Framework-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.29</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your `WebSecurityConfig` can't find the bean in `SQLConfig`. Modify `MessageWebApplicationInitializer`; try putting `SQLConfig.class` in `getRootConfigClasses()`:

```
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{ WebSecurityConfig.class, SQLConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{FreeMarkerConfig.class };
}

// ...
```

All the config classes in `getRootConfigClasses()` are used to create a parent application context, and those in `getServletConfigClasses()` are a child context. The child context can `@Autowire` root-context beans, but not the other way around.

Check out more info in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258758/getservletconfigclasses-vs-getrootconfigclasses-when-extending-abstractannot).