# Spring Boot Azure Storage Client yields java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NOOP_CONFIGURER

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, gradle, azure-storage

I'm trying to create a Spring Boot Application that is able to reach out to Azure Storage.

Here are some of the Dependencies I've attempted to declare in `build.gradle` thus far...

```
implementation 'com.azure:azure-storage-blob:+'    // Current Dependency

implementation 'com.azure.spring:azure-spring-boot-starter-storage:+'    // Previous Dependency
```

Both give me access to the `BlobServiceClient` class which I'm using to access my Azure Blob Container.

In my `application.properties` file, I have the following properties:

```
#Storage settings

# Current Attempt
azure.connection=${STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONNECTION}


# Previous Attempt
azure.storage.account-name=${STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}
azure.storage.account-key=${STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY}
azure.storage.blob-endpoint=${STORAGE_ACCOUNT_ENDPOINT}
```

I then use these properties in a Spring Service Class called `StorageService` to manage the `BlobServiceClient` . Here are my two attempts to set it up:

1 (Current).

```
    @Autowired
    StorageService(@Value("${azure.connection}") String connection)
    {

        client = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connection).buildClient();
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }
```

2. (Previous).

```
    @Autowired
    StorageService(@Value("${azure.storage.account-name}") String name,
                   @Value("${azure.storage.account-key}") String key,
                   @Value("${azure.storage.blob-endpoint}") String endpoint)
    {
        AzureNamedKeyCredential credential = new AzureNamedKeyCredential(name, key);
        client = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().credential(credential).endpoint(endpoint).buildClient();
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }
```

I even tried using both Java 11 and Java 17. However, each time I manage to run it in Intelli-J, I get this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NOOP_CONFIGURER

    at reactor.netty.ChannelPipelineConfigurer.emptyConfigurer(ChannelPipelineConfigurer.java:40)
    at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConfig.<init>(TransportConfig.java:207)
    at reactor.netty.transport.ClientTransportConfig.<init>(ClientTransportConfig.java:164)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConfig.<init>(HttpClientConfig.java:327)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect.<init>(HttpClientConnect.java:85)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient.create(HttpClient.java:393)
    at com.azure.core.http.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClientBuilder.build(NettyAsyncHttpClientBuilder.java:141)
    at com.azure.core.http.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClientProvider.createInstance(NettyAsyncHttpClientProvider.java:19)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.HttpClientProviders.createInstance(HttpClientProviders.java:67)
    at com.azure.core.http.HttpClient.createDefault(HttpClient.java:50)
    at com.azure.core.http.HttpClient.createDefault(HttpClient.java:40)
    at com.azure.core.http.HttpPipelineBuilder.build(HttpPipelineBuilder.java:73)
    at com.azure.storage.blob.implementation.util.BuilderHelper.buildPipeline(BuilderHelper.java:138)
    at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder.buildAsyncClient(BlobServiceClientBuilder.java:135)
    at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder.buildClient(BlobServiceClientBuilder.java:114)
    at com.trecapps.users.services.StorageService.<init>(StorageService.java:40)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

And when I googled `"NOOP_CONFIGURER"` (with the quotes), I get 2 results, so this error does not seem to be well documented. Any suggestions on how to get my app to launch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below points.

- `NoSuchField`, usually means that when linking the target class, the field
  is not there. But when compiling, the class should have that field,
  otherwise the code cann't compile.

> i.e; it indicates that an application tries to access or modify an
> object’s field, but that field no longer exists.

- This error can  occur during runtime, if the definition of a class
  has incompatibly changed.

1. The exception as shown is occurring at [***ChannelPipelineConfigurer***](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/9429eaa4c568f1d1fd1cb535335627516cca0aa6/reactor-netty-core/src/main/java/reactor/netty/ChannelPipelineConfigurer.java#L32) in empty configure method which returns NOOP_configurer which is present in `reactor netty  core`  under the ***package [reactor.netty](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/tree/9429eaa4c568f1d1fd1cb535335627516cca0aa6/reactor-netty-core/src/main/java/reactor/netty)***
2. This seems to be caused by version mismatch in  reactor-netty jar

***ChannelPipelineConfigurer.java***

```
package reactor.netty;

import io.netty.channel.Channel;
import reactor.util.annotation.Nullable;

import java.net.SocketAddress;

import static reactor.netty.ReactorNetty.CompositeChannelPipelineConfigurer.compositeChannelPipelineConfigurer;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface ChannelPipelineConfigurer {
    static ChannelPipelineConfigurer emptyConfigurer() {
        return ReactorNetty.NOOP_CONFIGURER;
}
```

So please check if reactor netty core release version incompatibility is the reason or one or more version conflicts occuring & try to upgrade to latest version of the release jar and also check if any incompatible dependencies are present.

To handle/deal with NoSuchFieldError error, try to clean all existing .class files and compile everything from the scratch.so  that verify that each referenced class is compiled to its latest version.

However, if the error is still thrown during runtime, then one may have to compile using one version of a library, but use another version at runtime. You must verify that your classpath contains the proper version of the specified library.

- [Reactive Spring Boot - java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
  DEFAULT_SHUTDOWN_QUIET_PERIOD - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62904221/reactive-spring-boot-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-default-shutdown-quiet-period)
- [spring-security-{noop}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60342529/spring-security-no-qualifying-bean-of-type-javax-sql-datasource-available-e#:%7E:text=username(%22user%22).password(%22-,%7Bnoop%7D,-password%22).roles)

Answer (score 0):

Added

```
    implementation "io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:+"
    implementation "io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:+"
```

to my `build.gradle` file.