# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'freemarkerConfig'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, freemarker

I want to send e-mails using Apache Freemaker I tried this:

```
@Service
public class EMailSender {

    @Autowired
    private Configuration freemarkerConfig;

    public void sendMail(String to, String subject, String content) {
        try {               freemarkerConfig.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "/templates");

            EmailRegistrationModel obj = new EmailRegistrationModel();
            obj.setMailSubject("Test");

            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            model.put("title", "Some name");
            obj.setModel(model);

            String data = geFreeMarkerTemplateContent(model);    
            helper.setText(data, true);

            mailSender.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String geFreeMarkerTemplateContent(Map<String, Object> model){
        StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
        try{
         content.append(FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString( 
                 freemarkerConfig.getTemplate("emails_activate.html"), model));
         return content.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception occured while processing fmtemplate:"+e.getMessage());
        }
          return "";
    }
}
```

Object for configuration:

```
public class EmailRegistrationModel {       
    private String mailContent;     
    private Map<String, Object> model;
    ....
}
```

When I deploy the code I get:

```
Error creating bean with name 'EMailSender': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'freemarkerConfig'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'freemarker.template.Configuration' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: getFreeMarkerConfiguration,freeMarkerConfiguration
```

Do you know how I can solve this issue? I suppose that I need to add some freemarker configuration? Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not that you have to few Freemarker configs but two much. Pay special attention to the last part of the exception message:

> No qualifying bean of type 'freemarker.template.Configuration' available: **expected single matching bean but found 2**: getFreeMarkerConfiguration,freeMarkerConfiguration

Spring Boot already comes with a [`FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/freemarker/FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration.html). Most probably you come with another one which you defined manually, could you verify this?

Please stick to the Freemarker section in the [application.properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) or in other words: configure you application with the `spring.freemarker.*` properties of Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1):

```
expected single matching bean but found 2: getFreeMarkerConfiguration,freeMarkerConfiguration
```

There may be a situation when you create more than one bean of the same type and want to wire only one of them with a property. In such cases, the above error comes. [Why this happened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173982/what-is-a-nosuchbeandefinitionexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

---

> Solution 1:
>   Use `@Resource` instead of `@Autowired` [Refer This](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

---

> Solution 2: Use `@Qualifier` [Refer This](https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/04/a-quality-qualifier)

---

> Solution 3: Use `@Primaray` [Refer This](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-primary)