# How should I solve the following error I get when using @Autowired annotation in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring and having some problems trying to use the @Autowired annotation, trying to inject the Repository class inside PostController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/posts")

public class PostController {


    @Autowired 
    private Repository repository;


    @RequestMapping(value="",method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listPosts(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("posts",repository.findAll());
        return "posts/lists";
    }
}

public interface Repository extends CrudRepository<Posts,Long> {
}
```

These are the error messages I get

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private domain.Repository controllers.PostController.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [domain.Repository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:759)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:958)
>       at MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:7)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private domain.Repository controllers.PostController.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [domain.Repository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
>       ... 16 more
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [domain.Repository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
>       ... 18 more

Comment: Use a setter? or declare it as a dependency on the constructor?

Comment: Annotate your repository with @Repository (But pick a different more specific name for your interface)

Comment: Agree with @Erwin Bolwidt Please Annotate your repository interface with **@Repository** and change your repository interface name like **PostsRepository**

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your own repository and extend it from repository, now you are using spring Repository interface.

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository<Posts,Long> {

}
```

and @Autowire it

```
@Autowired 
private PostRepository repository;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you log I suggest you to verify two points:

- is *domain*.**Repository** annotated with @Component?
- if the Application starts into the *controllers* package it will parse only the classes below the *controllers* package, that is excluding the *domain* package (where **Repository** is)

for the second point a quick fix you can either rearrange the packages under a **myapp** package and have the spring application start form a class at that level, or more [generic configurations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-auto-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

For good practices jpa, hibernate and especially for better handling of persistence exceptions you must add the @Repository annotation to all your repositories.

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository<Posts,Long> {

}
```

Now to instantiate the repository class you must do it as public.

```
@Autowired 
PostRepository postRepository;
```

Mention also that as good practice you create a service to handle all the logic of the process, where your repository is used.

Answer (score 0):

The exception here is NoSuchBeanDefinitionException .

Based on the [javadoc-api](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.html)

```
public class NoSuchBeanDefinitionException
extends BeansException

Exception thrown when a BeanFactory is asked for a bean instance for which it cannot find a definition. This may point to a non-existing bean, a non-unique bean, or a manually registered singleton instance without an associated bean definition.
```

There are many possibilities that could lead to this exception. Please read through this detailed explanation to get a complete picture. ->
[What is a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173982/what-is-a-nosuchbeandefinitionexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)