# How to inject Autowired beans inside XML configuration?

Tags: java, xml, spring, annotations

I have my Dao and DaoImpl classes as below:

```
public interface MyDao{
}
```

```
@Service(value = "MyDao")
public class MyDaoImpl implements MyDao{
}
```

I need MyDaoImpl inject to the variable myDao in the class Driver.java

```
public class Driver{
   MyDao myDao;
   public MyDao getMyDao() {
        return myDao;
   }
   public void setMyDao(MyDao myDao) {
        this.myDao = myDao;
   }
}
```

Now the problem is I am creating the bean using XML something like this :

```
<bean id="driver123" class="com.Driver">
</bean>
```

How do I inject an object of MyDaoImpl(created through Annotation) inside this bean using XML?
Had MyDaoImpl been created though XML, I could have used the property and ref config.

But how do I do here ?

Comment: _I could have using the property and ref config_ You can still do that. The bean's name is `ApiInboundManager`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can you please provide some code ?

Comment: As long as your XML or annotation configuration are importing one way or the other, `<property name="myDao" ref="ApiInboundManager" />`

Comment: You can try this.
`<bean id="driver123" class="com.Driver">
  <property name="myDao" ref="MyDao"></property>
 </bean>`

Comment: Tried the same. I am getting the exception while trying to get the bean in line cfg.getApplicationContext().getBean(beanId)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'MyDao' available

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173982/what-is-a-nosuchbeandefinitionexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: I mentioned earlier _As long as your XML or annotation configuration are importing one way or the other_. Make sure you're doing that.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis As long as your XML or annotation configuration are importing one way or the other --> I am not very clear on this. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

First You create Config Class for Configuration like this

```
package com.example.amer.config;

import com.example.amer.dao.MyDaoImpl;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean(name = "myDaoImpl")
    public MyDaoImpl myDaoImpl()
    {
        MyDaoImpl myDao = new MyDaoImpl();
        return myDao;
    }
}
```

here we create MyDaoImpl Bean

and MyDao interface

```
package com.example.amer.dao;

public interface MyDao {

    public String getUserByName();
}
```

and the Driver class

```
package com.example.amer;

import com.example.amer.dao.MyDao;

public class Driver {
    MyDao myDao;

    public MyDao getMyDao() {
        return myDao;
    }

    public void setMyDao(MyDao myDao) {
        this.myDao = myDao;
    }

}
```

next i will create the xml beans like this

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Scan the JavaConfig -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.amer.config" />

    <bean id="driver" class="com.example.amer.Driver">
        <property name="myDao" ref="myDaoImpl"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

here in xml we scan about Java Configuration that contains MyDao Impl
the i create the Driver bean and define to myDao Property then i refer to MyDaoImpl bean with it's name defined in @Bean(name="myDaoImpl")

so it will work.