# spring is looking for bean named with wrong capitalization for first letter

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean that I am positive is in the package being scanned by spring (all its siblings work successfully).

```
@Service
class BeanB {

}

@Service
@DependsOn("BeanB")
class BeanA {

  @Autowired
  BeanB b;

}
```

However when I run it I get this:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'BeanB' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:682)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1218)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297)
    ... 34 more
```

However `BeanB` is present.

When I drill into the spring internals (DefaultListableBeanFactory beanDefinitionMap), it says that it has a bean named `beanB`.  Why is spring not able to find and wire the correct `@AutoWired` (or `@Inject` bean, it appears the capitalization is off for the first letter?

I have looked at [What is a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173982/what-is-a-nosuchbeandefinitionexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) but it doesn't seem to deal with the case of "my bean is in there but can't be found from capitalization"

Comment: The linked duplicate has a section named "Using wrong bean name" that explains how a bean is named and how to refer to it.

Comment: OK yeah that's it.  It's too bad that googling "wrong capitaliztion"  for bean didn't take me there.  Hopefully this question won't get deleted, for followers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't dying trying to find the right bean to autowire, the actual culprite was the `@DependsOn` but it sure threw me for a loop, so documenting it here.

Fix: use spring style class -> name convention:

```
@DependsOn("beanB")
class BeanA {

...
```

Comment: Just for the information, annotating `BeanB` with `@Service(value = "BeanB")` would also have worked.

Comment: "the problem was actually in the DependsOn vs. the normal AutoWired" wrinkle...