# Spring boot unable to autowire class in tests after disable JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot

hope you all are doing well

I'm facing some problems on testing my Spring Boot application. I created a simple API (currently has only one method, and it's working) and I created the domain tests disabling JPA configurations. When I test with JPA disabled, the tests provide the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.mhrehbein.curriculum.register.infrastructure.mysql.ISpringDataAboutMeRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

When I enable JPA configuration it works fine, but I would like to disable once it is unit tests. You can check the code in the following PR: https://github.com/retatu/curriculum/pull/6/files (sorry for it)

In the code you can see that all tests are broke, the tests are basically the same and the example is here: https://github.com/retatu/curriculum/blob/dev/src/test/java/com/mhrehbein/curriculum/register/domain/entity/AboutMeTest.java

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you declared an interface that extends `PagingAndSortingRepository`:

```
public interface ISpringDataAboutMeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<AboutMe, UUID> {
}
```

It means that spring boot must autoconfigure this repository bean for you, namely, it will be configured a proxy bean of [`SimpleJpaRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html).

But since you disabled `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` in `application-test.properties`, no `DataSource` bean is configured, therefore the automatic [`JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jpa/JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.html) is not activated and user-defined JPA-repositories, in your case `ISpringDataAboutMeRepository`, are **not registered**, which leads to the `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`. More info  about it [here](https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/automatic-configuration-of-springboot-spring-data-jpa.html).

Also, if you disable `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration`, `EntityManagerFactory` bean isn't configured, which is necessary to create your `ISpringDataAboutMeRepository` bean.

As a result, if you want to run `@SpringBootTest`, you need to remove your `spring.autoconfigure.exclude` property from `application-test.properties` and configure a database for tests, e.g. in-memory H2-database:

Add to your `build.gradle`:

```
testImplementation group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.200'
```

Your `application-test.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
```

Otherwise, you can use `@MockBean` annotation on your test classes to mock your `ISpringDataAboutMeRepository` so:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) // remove it since  @SpringBootTest already contains it
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@MockBean(ISpringDataAboutMeRepository.class)
public class AboutMeTest {
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring has it's spring application context which is working as a container of beans. The `BeanFactory` represents spring's inversion of control container. What it does is exposing beans to the application. When your application requires a bean which is not available then it throws `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

I think your question and the root cause is best answered in the below question. Hope it will five you insights of the problem.

[What is a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173982/what-is-a-nosuchbeandefinitionexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)