# Error Rest API Springboot Security Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

> Error:
> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through field 'profileNotFoundException'; nested exception
> is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'com.Portfolio.API.Exception.ProfileNotFoundException' available:
> expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
> Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>
> Description:
>
> Field profileNotFoundException in
> com.Portfolio.API.Config.SecurityConfig required a bean of type
> 'com.Portfolio.API.Exception.ProfileNotFoundException' that could not
> be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'com.Portfolio.API.Exception.ProfileNotFoundException' in your
> configuration.

My Config:

```
 package com.Portfolio.API.Config;

import com.Portfolio.API.Exception.ProfileNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ProfileNotFoundException profileNotFoundException;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()   // Esto permite que cualquiera entre a cualquier parte de tu página web
                /*
                // Con esto puedes controlar quien entra a qué partes de tu aplicación/página dependiendo del rol que tengan
                .antMatchers("/home").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/education").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/experience").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/projects").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/skills").hasRole("USER")
                */
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()    // Se crea una página de login para identificarse
                .and()
                .httpBasic();

        return http.build();
    }

    // Aquí se crean los usuarios con sus passwords y roles y se guardan en la memoria del programa,
    // al terminar la ejecución, se borran
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
        UserDetails user = User
                .withUsername("user")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("123456"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        UserDetails admin = User
                .withUsername("admin")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, admin);
    }

    // Con este método se encriptan los passwords
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

**My github repo: https://github.com/cynthiasaucedo/PortfolioAP/tree/master/Backend**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173982/what-is-a-nosuchbeandefinitionexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Try by annotating `ProfileNotFoundException` class with `@Component`

Answer (score 1):

you have this error `Field profileNotFoundException in com.Portfolio.API.Config.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'com.Portfolio.API.Exception.ProfileNotFoundException'  that could not be found.`

so try to remove field with ProfileNotFoundException name;

Answer (score -1):

It seems the spring boot is unable to inject the profileNotFoundException bean you should check that. Also I can see that you haven't used it in this class so you can either check and build your application again by removing this

```
@Autowired
private ProfileNotFoundException profileNotFoundException;
```

As you the bean is not defined for this name and it seems to be a custom exception which you can throw directly when necessary. Check if it works.

Comment: Autowired required false only sets the reference to null, which will generate a NPE when used. This doesn't solve the problem that the bean has not been defined.

Comment: Yes I am sorry i edited the solution too that it should be removed